# Stand-alone, yet closely related functions at module level

Tags: python, class

By 'stand-alone' I mean functions not inside a class (I'm not sure of the correct terminology - 'module-level'?)

I have ~7 functions in a file that already has a few classes.These functions deal with processing input from the command line, reading and writing to files, checking whether file paths are valid - that kind of thing. Their purposes are closely related, and yet I'm not sure whether to put them into their own class because I can't think of any reason to instantiate such a class, or any states that would be associated with it.

What are my options, and what would you recommend I do with these functions? Is the use of static methods discouraged/unnecessary in Python?

Comment: That's perfectly fine. And you're right about the class part - if there's no reason to put them in one, then don't. The python standard libs use it all the time as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standalone module-level functions are totally fine if their functionality is related to that of the module. Just take a look at the Python standard library modules, they usually contain both functions and classes for a given topic.